# Finding unique pairs between nodes in Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am using [Cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/). I have some nodes connected with edges.

I want to loop through each connection between two nodes. The problem is that in some cases, two nodes have multiple edges between them, so I cannot just say `cy.edges().forEach()` because it will result in looping through more edges than needed.

What I could do is to say something like

```
const alreadyVisited = [];

cy.edges().forEach(edge => {
  const key1 = edge.source() + '-' + edge.target();
  const key2 = edge.target() + '-' + edge.source();

  if (alreadyVisited.indexOf(key1) === -1 && alreadyVisited.indexOf(key2)) {
    // ...
    alreadyVisited.push(key1);
    alreadyVisited.push(key2);
  }
})
```

but it seems a bit stupid. Cytoscape has some functions `edges.parallelEdges()`, `nodes.connectedEdges()`, `eles.neighborhood()`, etc. Wouldn't it be possible to solve my problem utilizing some of them?

The reason for having both `key1` and `key2`  is because I didn't know how to make sure that the direction of the edge doesn't matter.

## Edit

I could, alternatively, also do something like

```
cy.nodes().forEach(node1 => {
  cy.nodes().forEach(node2 => {
    if (node1 !== node2) {
      // now I have each pair
    }
  });
});
```

but isn't it also a stupid approach since many of them won't have edges between them? And if I have two nodes A and B, this approach will give 2 relations (both A -> B and B -> A).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the traversing functions: http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/traversing

For example, `node.edgesWith( node2 )` gives undirected edges between the nodes whereas `node.edgesTo( node2 ) gives directed ones.`node.connectedEdges()` may also be of interest if you want to focus on one node and all its connections rather than a specific pair of nodes.

The collections of elements can be used as sets, so you can do `toTraverse = toTraverse.difference( justTraversed )` if you want to keep track of things.